# why wont my printf float display? (beginner)

Tags: c

this is the code i wrote for my school program 
my question is why wont the printf show the float value it comes up as inf ( which i believe is infinity?) i know my values previously are all int's which if why i put float in () 
anyways help is appreciated

cheerzx

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int c1, c2, c3, parallelCap;
    float seriesCap;

    printf("please enter the value of the first resistor:");
    scanf(" %d", &c1);
    printf("please enter the value of the second rstr:");
    scanf(" %d", &c2);
    printf("please enter the value of the third resistor:");
    scanf(" %d", &c3);
    parallelCap = c1 + c2 + c3;
    seriesCap = (float)1/(1/c1 + 1/c2 + 1/c3);
    printf("the parallel capacitance is: %d the series 
    capacitance is: %f/n ", parallelCap, seriesCap);
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: All the divisions in `1/c1 + 1/c2 + 1/c3` are done using integer arithmetic, so they're all `0`.

Comment: Change it to `1.0/c1 + 1.0/c2 + 1.0/c3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting `inf` because each of `1/c1 + 1/c2 + 1/c3` evaluates to `0` when `c1`, `c2` and `c2` are greater than `1` and so you end up dividing `1` by `0`. This is because it works as integer division. You can either cast each one of them separately to float or use `1.0` as numerator like this

```
seriesCap = 1.0/(1.0/c1 + 1.0/c2 + 1.0/c3);
```

Comment: accepting the answer would suffice <3

Comment: check mark ? sorry im new

Comment: Don't sweat it! It's perfectible fine :)